# Migrating from mysql_result() to updated method

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code that I am changing to `mysqli`:

```
   $result = Data::searchForUser($updateusername);
        if (mysql_result($result, 0) > 0) {
            $message = "3";
        } else {
        $result = Data::updateUserName($updateusername, $user);
            if ($result == true) {
                $message = "1";
            } else {
                $message = "2";
            }
        }
```

My question: I can't figure out a `mysqli` equivalant.  Or is this method still good?  or should I be using something like `mysqli_num_rows` OR `mysqli_fetch_row` here?

I don't get an error, I get message 3 every time.

Comment: If you're updating code how about looking into PDOs if you're on PHP5 ?

Comment: PDO is a lot better than `mysqli` because of the named placeholders feature. Much easier to bind arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try using `mysqli_result` with `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

[mysqli_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

[mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Also, I would definitely quit using `mysql_result` as all the mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: That's what they're trying to do, quit using it, but are asking how.

Comment: Yes, but he also asked if the old method was still good. The answer is no because it is deprecated.

Comment: I don't understand how you use both? Or do you mean either/or?

Comment: Also, I get `Call to undefined function mysqli_result()`

Comment: Sorry about that. The `mysqli_result` is just the class that holds several functions. The function you want to try is the `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.